# Getting user input

Tags: c++, input

I have a problem at this line

```
cout << "Please input how many hours your pool pump ran this month: ";

cin.get(hours,15);

cin.ignore(80,'\n');
```

around there the program skips over were you would enter your hours. I can't find solution of the problem if You want to see the whole code it is on my other posts. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it simpler like this:

```
int hours = 0;
cout << "Please input how many hours your pool pump ran this month: "
cin >> hours;
```

For reasons why your code didn't work as expected, check the `cin.get()` and `cin.ignore()` documentation:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/